# git clone without .git extension

Tags: git, ssh

im working with git and a remote repo using ssh. everything is fine. the remote repository is a production server and I want to make "git push" to the up level directory which should not have a .git extension. now how can i make add remote repo without the .git ? 
 can anybody help?

Comment: You should not push to non-bare repositories. Use hooks to let another repository pull changes from the bare one.

Comment: thanks. but how can i achieve that?

Comment: @kabiridris: see http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto for details

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the complete path to git clone command:

```
git clone <original-repo> <directory-path>
```

If the remote repo already exists, it doesn't matter wether it has a .git extension, add it as a remote with its full path.

Also, you should read the relevant resources on deploying a git repo. For example [this one](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)

Comment: how do i specify the ssh directory-path?

Comment: clone destination directory must be on the same machine so log in ssh and issue the clone command from here. This obviously has to be done only the first time

Comment: does that mean the remote server most have git installed?

Comment: It's not mandatory; can you clarify what command do you currently use for cloning?

Comment: git clone prod ssh://user@server.com/public_html

Comment: You on the wrong way, you don't clone to a remote URL, you clone from a URL. So yes, either install git on the server, or use git-ftp.